# Сползает текст в мобильной версий

Tags: html, css

Доброго утра всем

Когда смотришь в полном размере сайт, то кнопки нормально отображаться
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А когда заходишь с телефона то выглядит так

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите как исправить.

```
<p>
  <a href="zapis-na-kursy.html">
    <span style="font-size: 14pt; color: #fff; background: red; border-radius: 8px; padding: 5px 5px 5px;">Запись на курс</span>
  </a> 
  <a href="zapisatsya-kak-model.html">
     <span style="font-size: 14pt; color: #fff; background: red; border-radius: 8px; padding: 5px 5px 5px;">Записаться как модель</span>
  </a>
</p>
```

Comment: Если картинка на телефоне полная, то всё правильно. Ширина блока такая...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Такое происходит, потому что тэг "a" отображается как строчный элемент, а не строчный блок (прошу прощения за словесную абракадабру). Если поставить в стилях отображение его как inline-block и добавить отступы сверху и снизу, получится на порядок правильнее. [И сам пример](https://jsfiddle.net/knzmbvye/).

```
a {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 10px 0
}
```

Comment: Вышло что кнопки сползли вниз

Comment: а как должно происходить ?

Comment: Они наползают на белую линию  В мобильной версий все нормально, а вот на пк наползает на текст снизу

Comment: http://pixs.ru/showimage/SnimokGIF_6201721_19629448.gif

Comment: Поменяйте на своем сайте, вот эти стили.

#jm-top-bar {
height: auto;
padding: 0;
top: 0;
}

.topbar #jm-header {
    padding-top: 54px;
}

Comment: Нечего не произошло, слазил логотип только вниз

Comment: Сделал по другому.